# start php session on successful ldap login

Tags: php, session

It seems variations for questions about starting PHP sessions are very common but I have not come across any description for my problem.

I am using ldap_bind to have users authenticate in my site and I only want them to access pages behind the login if they authenticate successfully.

To do this I believe I need to create a PHP session but should I create the PHP session at the start of my login page or should it only be created if they successfully authenticate with the `ldap_bind`?

If it is the latter then should I just be putting `session_start();` in my if statement used to check if the username and password provided works for the LDAP bind and if it does should I be calling session username in the `'protected'` pages?

My ldap bind is pretty simple:

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("11.222.33.44")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, "uid=$username,cn=users,dc=abc,dc=net", "$password");

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
worked
sessinon_start();
} else {
didnt work } }
```

possible code at the top of my protected pages:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username']); {
session_start();
} else {
send back to login? 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the session at the beginning of page and set the session on the successful ldap bind . No you don't need call username in protected pages as ldap is itself a windows authentication

```
 session_start();
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("11.222.33.44")
or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

// binding to ldap server
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, "uid=$username,cn=users,dc=abc,dc=net", "$password");

// verify binding
if ($ldapbind) {
$_SESSION['username']=username;
} else {
//didnt work } }
```

Comment: Do i need this at the top of every protected page or just the first page and then have session_start at the top of every protected page?

Comment: in the other pages just start_session() and then check for a value in $_SESSION array exists (i.e. username)

Comment: Would that look like this at the top of any protected page: session_start(); if (isset($_SESSION['username']);